# How to programatically modify contents of an excel sheet via excel web services in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services

I have read that, While users can interact with Excel workbooks in a browser through Excel Services, the workbooks cannot be edited in the browser by using Excel Services. Programmatic options are available.

I would like to know what is the programmatic method, could you provide any links or reference please?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the OpenXML libraries to manipulate the excel file (as long as it is a .xlsx file).

Here are some links to get you started:

- [MSDN Site for OpenXML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx).
- [Example of how to open a workbook from a stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478410.aspx).